# anomaly detection alert system

Tags: java, anomaly-detection

I need to design and implement my 3rd year project which is a real-time alert system for parents to keep their kids safe with their smartphones.

My data is time-based and unsupervised, which means I don't have score for any events, it contains events from :

- mobile browsing ( http requests )
- gps coordinates
- calls ( outgoing & incoming )

Should I choose cluster based / density based approach ? 
How do I find rare & suspicious events that parents should be notified for with the help of machine learning ?

Any suggestions on how to present the results visually ?

Is a week of data enough for training ?

Are there any good open sources in Java to detect anomaly ?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I choose cluster based / density based approach?

**Yes,** but depends on how good the algorithm is, and how effectively is the algorithm identifying important clusters. There is [a lot of literature](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/courses/msc/projects/PastDissertations/2012-2013/Dissertations/Elangovan.pdf) where people have taken the clustering approach.

If I were to go with the clustering approach, I would go with the [hierarchical clustering technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering), cause it would help me re-check my clusters and build hierarchies in them so that the seriousness of the fraud can also be explored.

> How do I find rare & suspicious events that parents should be notified
>   for with the help of machine learning ?

I would point out [an answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/8100/11097) which I have written for a very similar question, which also explores the aspect of fraud detection and anomaly analysis. And as I have said in the answer, the genetic algorithm still goes strong when it comes to fraud detection, owing to it's neat method of fitness calculation of the data points.

> Any suggestions on how to present the results visually ?

Generally such charts are presented through pie charts and network graphs. you can also use infographics if you have a nice idea about design and aesthetics.

> Is a week of data enough for training ?

Generally, data science teams at Paypal, Palantir, etc churn years of data for sensible insights. As you say it's a class project, data of several months should do good. **You wouldn't really get anything suspicious or sensible from a week of data.**

> Are there any good open sources in Java to detect anomaly ?

Yes, there are some:

1. [Genetic algorithms library](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/)
2. [A Distributed Online Machine Learning Framework in java](http://jubat.us/en/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, I know what the parameters are, isn't that the main factor to for choosing an algorithm ?  do you have any ideas for pre-processing stage, how to split this parameters into sub-parameters ?

Comment: @huji1991 Glad you liked the answer(you can also upvote it if it helped :)). Generally, the parameters/threshold depends on the problem domain. For example, a particular stretch of internet time might be okay for US kids, and might not go well with Indian kids.  So, the **context is the key**, when dealing with fraud detection problems!

Comment: I need reputation to upvote (15points+)

Comment: It's okay :) And welcome to the site!